# Batch screenshots with FFmpeg

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I have this bat file that works with another software and I would like to modify it to work with FFmpeg but I haven't been able to get the syntax or arguments correct

I essentially have a series of 1hr videos on an external HDD I want to extract an screenshot every 15mins to folder on my computer.  I could do it successfully with FFmpeg from the CMD but not in a bat file.

```
@echo off
pause

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('dir E:\BIW\*.asf /b') DO "c:\Program Files (x86)\FrameShots3\fsconsole.exe" -ms 900000 -width 1920 -height 1080 -filetype JPEG -filename BIW_ -filecounter 0000 "E:\BIW\%%A" "C:\timelapse\BIW\"
pause
```

Comment: Show your `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: I guess I should clarify that I was able to use the CMD arguments for FFMpeg on one file as per the support wiki. ffmpeg -i myvideo.avi -vf fps=1/60 img%03d.jpg I just haven't been able to get it to work in a for loop bat file similar to what ive done with Frameshots

Comment: For batch, try changing `img%03d.jpg` to `img%%03d.jpg`.